# Generic term for either debit or credit

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, hypernyms, finance

In double-entry accounting, transactions are a [series of debits and credits applied onto various accounts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debits_and_credits).

What English term could be used to represent something that is either a debit or a credit in a transaction (without specifically saying which one it is)?

Something like "ledger entry", but "ledger entry" is too vague.

Comment: Since each is an entry, please say why "ledger entry" is too vague. What else could it be but an entry signifying either a debit or a credit?

Comment: Yes, I guess "ledger entry" could work, or alternatively "account entry". I'm just wondering if a term actually exists to represent that.

Comment: "Posting" as in _there are five **postings** in xyz account: two are journals and the other three are from the cash book_. Some use the term "booking".

Comment: I was about to suggest "transaction" until I re-read the sentence and realized that it was defining that term as a collection of the items you designate generically.  If the terms "debit" and "credit" are also defined terms or terms of art in this context (e.g. a textbook or common accounting terminology), then a collective term for them in general English usage is irrelevant.

Comment: @PellMel But it's not irrelevant. The OP is seeking a neutral term (neither debit nor credit) in book-keeping for the entries in the ledgers. "Posting", "booking" or just "entry" are widely used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked in finance for a long time, and the usual word was "booking", or sometimes "entry".